# Custom post type loop the parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

On single.php i have a standard WP loop which displays post content.

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <article>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>              
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</main>
```

Bellow it i have simple loop that displays 3 latest custom post type items

```
<div class="manuals">

            <?php
                    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type' => 'manuals',
                            'posts_per_page' => 3
                        )
                    );
            ?>

            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); // Fullsize image for the single post ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>         
                                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>    
</div>
```

Both the posts and custom post type share 2 WP categories (simple, advanced).
If the user opens up an article which is posted in "advanced" category , i would like the custom post type only to show posts from "advanced" category...

Hope you understood what i mean, english isnt my first language... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, your simple/advanced categories are mutually exclusive, so you can assume that there is one and only one category on the current blog post. Assuming that's the case, you first want to get the current post's category with [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) and then pass that category to your custom query via [`tax_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters).

Something like this should work:

```php
// main loop up here...

// get terms (categories) from the current post
$cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');

// default args for querying our manual posts
$manuals_query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'manuals',
  'posts_per_page' => 3
);

// filter manuals by category, if and only if current post is categorized
if (isset($cats[0])) {
  $cat_id = $cats[0]->term_id;
  $manuals_query_args['tax_query'] = array(
    // note that tax_query needs to be an *array of arrays* -
    // in this case, an array containing just one array
    array(
      'taxomony' => 'category',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => $cat_id
    )
  );
}

$loop = new WP_Query($manuals_query_args);
```

You may have to tweak it, I didn't test this code.

Comment: i cant thank you enough but to be honest, i dont know how to implement this,complete newb here... adding <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> breaks everything at start

Comment: @Stojko please edit your question to include the new code, along with any errors messages you get, and I'll try to help out. It might also be helpful to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php if you haven't.

Comment: hi @acobster, sorry for late message. i have added my current code above, if you could take a look it would mean a whole lot to me

Comment: @Stojko you need to edit your question with the code you're trying out, and explain how it "breaks everything." It general on stackoverflow you need to demonstrate what you've tried and how it doesn't work. When you do so, please add it to your question as a new version of the code, so that we can keep the older version as a reference. Also, I just realized that the last line of my code snippet had a typo (now fixed), so keep that in mind. :)